# udev rule running setserial low_latency don't work

Tags: ntp, ubuntu-14.04, udev, serial, gps

My server runs Ubuntu 14.04.1. I created *udev* rules in `/etc/udev/rules.d/09-pps.rules` to get GPS with PPS support work.

```
KERNEL=="ttyS0", SYMLINK+="gps0", MODE="0666"
KERNEL=="ttyS0", RUN+="/bin/setserial -q /dev/%k low_latency"
KERNEL=="ttyS0", RUN+="/usr/sbin/ldattach pps /dev/%k"
```

`/dev/pps0` will appear at startup. All right.
If I check _low_latency_ flag it looks like

```
$ sudo setserial -a /dev/ttyS0
/dev/ttyS0, Line 0, UART: 16550A, Port: 0x03f8, IRQ: 4
        Baud_base: 115200, close_delay: 50, divisor: 0
        closing_wait: 3000
        Flags: spd_normal skip_test

$ sudo setserial /dev/ttyS0 low_latency
$ sudo setserial -a /dev/ttyS0
/dev/ttyS0, Line 0, UART: 16550A, Port: 0x03f8, IRQ: 4
        Baud_base: 115200, close_delay: 50, divisor: 0
        closing_wait: 3000
        Flags: spd_normal skip_test low_latency
```

Why is low_latency always missing after startup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the following:

```
KERNEL=="ttyS0", RUN+="/bin/setserial /dev/ttyS0 low_latency"
KERNEL=="ttyS0", SYMLINK+="gps0", RUN+="/usr/sbin/ldattach pps /dev/ttyS0"
KERNEL=="pps0", OWNER="root", GROUP="dialout", MODE="0660", SYMLINK+="gpspps0"
```

Did you test your udev rule with udevadm:?

```
 # udevadm  test  /sys/class/tty/ttyS0
```

#### Update

Your setserial configuration might be a problem. Check the configuration of setserial:

```
 # dpkg-reconfigure -p low setserial
```

I selected "autosave always." Try "autosave always" and then verify the low_latency setting before rebooting. If that does not work try selecting "kernel" when you do the dpkg-reconfigure

You can verify that things match up by investigating /var/lib/setserial.

When I reboot setserial says:

```
 # setserial -G /dev/ttyS0
 /dev/ttyS0 uart 16550A port 0x03f8 irq 4 baud_base 115200 spd_normal skip_test low_latency
```

Which matches what is found in /var/lib/setserial

```
 # cat /var/lib/setserial/autoserial.conf |grep -v ^\#
 /dev/ttyS0 uart 16550A port 0x03f8 irq 4 baud_base 115200 spd_normal skip_test low_latency
```

NB: Sometimes the entry in setserial will say 8250 instead of 16550A. I do not know why this happens on some machines but it has never been an issue for me when they differ.

Comment: Thanks for the test hint. There was no error in the test. _ldattach_ was executed successful. I switched to your version but still no low_latency after startup. Which priority (filename) do you have?

Comment: Have you checked once if the low_latency attribute is set?

Comment: Yes this works with my servers. I have added one more thing to my answer you should check. If this answer is helpful please mark it as accepted.